# How to unit test a super() call in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following mixin:

```py
class MixinToAddOnMyClass:
    def get_data(self, request):
        try:
            data = super().get_processed_data(request)
        except Exception:
            data = {'error': 'Invalid data request'}
```

I'd like to test this mixin class - but I find it not so clean when I have to create a mock class to inherit from it so that I can test the `super()` call.

What would be the best way to unit test it?

Comment: Can you show how you're currently doing it? "Best way" is pretty difficult to gauge without context.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up finding a way to do it. It seems like you can mock built in methods:

```py
    @patch('<path_to_mixin_file>.super')
    def test_get_data_when_no_exception(self, super):
        super.get_processed_data.return_value = True
        self.assertTrue(MixinToAddOnMyClass.run_validation())
```